# Problems using opam and ocaml

Tags: bash, ocaml, ubuntu-14.04, opam

I am working on RDP having Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install ocaml.

I am trying to update my ocaml compiler to 4.05.0 or above but `opam switch list` gives only one compiler `system C system  System compiler (4.01.0)`. Also my `opam update` gives me below log.

```
[ERROR] Your version of OPAM (1.1.1) is not recent enough to read ~/.opam/repo/default/repo. Upgrade OPAM to a more recent version (at least 2.0) to read this file correctly.
[ERROR] Skipping https://opam.ocaml.org as the repository is not available.
Updating ~/.opam/repo/compiler-index ...
Updating ~/.opam/compilers/ ...
Updating ~/.opam/repo/package-index ...
Updating ~/.opam/packages/ ...
Updating the cache of metadata (~/.opam/state.cache) ...
Everything is up-to-date.
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks for help in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
I need to install newer opam version separately using binary distribution. with this

```
sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)
```

command I can install it but it will prompt me where to install it, 
but I have to automate installation so that there is no interaction from user side. Is there a way to do it?

**UPDATE 2:**

found a way to do it using ppa see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)` but failed in doing it as non-interactive script.

I have found this method which does work, though using Ubuntu 14.04 adding ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa` and then doing update, upgrade, dist-upgrade and finally installation of opam will be of version 2.2 (latest as by ppa). Follow below commands for exact procedure.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:avsm/ppa
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
apt-get install curl build-essential m4 zlib1g-dev libssl-dev ocaml ocaml-native-compilers opam -y
opam init --disable-sandboxing -y
eval `opam config env`
opam update
opam switch list-available
opam switch create 4.07.0
opam init -y
eval `opam config env`
```

After this Everything should be latest as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the log says you have to update your OPAM to 2.x. The old version is no longer supported. So you have to follow the [installation instructions](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html) and update your OCaml.

Comment: @user:2625442 I am using pipeline for installation of opam and I have to automate the installation do you know any way this can be done. i,e `sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)` will prompt with where to install. Is there any way to force directory or something similar?

Comment: ideally, you should find a prebuilt package for your automated system (e.g., using a correct docker or vagrant base image). Though, in the general case you can still run an interactive script in an autonomous mode, for the `install.sh` it is as easy as `echo "" | sh ./install.sh`. This will work provided that you have sufficient permissions. Otherwise either add permissions (via sudo) or change the location to something where you can install without extra permissions, e.g., `echo "/home/user/bin" | sh ./install.sh`